# Using NLTK to find morphologically related verbs to some given noun

Tags: nlp, nltk

How would I go about extracting the morphologically related verb(s) for some noun.

So, for example, I would like to be able to build some function like this (using nltk):

```
related_verb('decision') -> 'decide'
related_verb('walk') -> 'walk'
related_verb('shower') -> 'shower'
related_verb('exclusion') -> 'exclude'
```

This is really simple to do using the '-derin' command (http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wn.1WN.html#toc). But I can't seem to be able to do the same thing with nltk. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could help:

Get lemma:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
lem = wn.lemmas('exclusion')[0]
print lem

>>> Lemma('exclusion.n.01.exclusion')
```

Get related forms:

```
related_forms = lem.derivationally_related_forms()
print related_forms

>>> [Lemma('bar.v.01.exclude'), Lemma('exclude.v.02.exclude')]
```

Get names of related verb lemmas:

```
print [related_form.name for related_form in related_forms
      if related_form.synset.pos == 'v']

>>> ['exclude', 'exclude']
```